# Recuperar o id da URL sem perder nenhum parâmetro - PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Bom dia senhores. 
Pode ser que não seja uma boa prática, alias, é bom provavel que não seja, mas estou passando alguns parametros na minha URL por javascript para recuperar em PHP.

Estou passando assim no javascript. 
*href="analyze?id='+ par1 +'|'+ par2 + '"*

ai na URL, fica assim, meio estranho de entender, mas até então OK. 
*analyze?id=122963|09.27.09%204%S%20+%200,2%B%20+%200,5%CU%20+%200,3%ZN*

os dois parâmetros separados por '|', mas ai que o bicho pega.

no momento em que recupero pelo $_GET['id'], acontece o seguinte, eu utilizo o explode para pegar cada um dos parametros, mas o segundo parametro, era para vir assim "09.27.09 4%S + 0,2%B + 0,5%CU + 0,3%ZN", com os sinais de +, porém, os sinais não aparecem, eles sumiram.

Eu até pensei em criptografar a url, mas não sei fazer isso no javascript e depois descriptografar no PHP, nem sei se funciona na verdade, mas queria algo mais simples, que no final se tornou dificil.

Aguardo uma resposta. 
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Tente usando `encodeURIComponent(par2)`.

Comment: você tbm pode usar a varivel global do php **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**,
exemplo **$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**, logo depois só você usar metodos pra corta o que é retornado

Comment: O sinal `+` é um caractere válido que pode ser usado em um URL e tem um significado. Se você quer passar uma string que contenha este caractere, faça com o @Sam sugeriu, use [`encondeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). Ex.: `href="analyze?id=' + encodeURIComponent(par1 + '|' + par2)`

Comment: Só que seria melhor você fazer isso através de um formulário, evitaria muita dor de cabeça.

Comment: @fernandosavio deu certinho, era isso mesmo. MUITO obrigada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os sinais de `+` não aparecem pois o PHP esta se perdendo na hora de fazer o decode dos parâmetros.
Pelo que entendi você esta "encodando" os caracteres especiais manualmente na hora de formar a sua URL (`analyze?id=122963|09.27.09%204%S%20+%200,2%B%20+%200,5%CU%20+%200,3%ZN`) e é exatamente isso que esta causando o problema.
A solução é utilizar o método urlencode para criar o link com os parâmetros.
Segue um exemplo abaixo.

```
<?php
    //Informe os parâmetros exatamente como você quer que seja exibido.
    $params = '09.27.09 4%S + 0,2%B + 0,5%CU + 0,3%ZN';
    //Encodando os params para substituir os caracteres especiais
    $encodedParams = urlencode($params);

    $encodeManual = '09.27.09%204%S%20+%200,2%B%20+%200,5%CU%20+%200,3%ZN';

    echo '<h2>Usando urlencode = '.$encodedParams.'</h2>';
    echo '<h2>Encode Manual    = '.$encodeManual.'</h2>';

    echo '<h1>Decode da url encodada manualmente = '.urldecode($encodeManual).'</h1>';
    echo '<h1>Decode da url encodada por urlencode = '.urldecode($encodedParams).'</h1>';

?>
```

Obs: Depois de buscar os parâmetros com o `$_GET[ ]` não precisa utilizar o `urldecode`, só utilizei no exemplo para mostrar como ele decoda a sua url feita manualmente e a outra criada pela função `urlencode`.